# Convert columns to dts list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
   from        to
2019-01-01   2019-05-01  
2019-02-01   2019-04-01
2019-03-01   2019-06-01
```

I want to convert this to set the range of dates as (start, end) tuples in dts list:

Except output:

```
dts = [('2019-01-01', '2019-05-01'), ('2019-02-01', '2019-04-01'),('2019-03-01', '2019-06-01')]
```

Note: conversion in a generalize way - if I add new rows to each column, code would not change.

Comment: Since it's probably related to my answer in another question, `dts` doesn't even have to be a list of tuples: a list of lists or a 2D numpy array will work fine as well. To get a numpy array you can simply do `dts = df.values`

Comment: @perl thanks for the follow up on this.  would the dts = df.apply(tuple,1).tolist() work in this case.. or would you suggest dts=df.vaules.

Comment: asking because this is directly related to your previous answer

Comment: Both are OK, `df.values` is just a bit shorter to write, but no difference really

Comment: @AnuragDabas Was still testing the solution but thank you! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply use `apply()` method and `tolist()` method:

```
dts=df.apply(tuple,1).tolist()
```

Now if you print `dts` you will get your desired output:

```
print(dts)

#output
[('2019-01-01', '2019-05-01'), ('2019-02-01', '2019-04-01'), ('2019-03-01', '2019-06-01')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df.values.tolist()
Out[222]: 
[['2019-01-01', '2019-05-01'],
 ['2019-02-01', '2019-04-01'],
 ['2019-03-01', '2019-06-01']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways:

```
df.to_records(index=False).tolist()

pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df).tolist()

list(map(tuple,df.to_numpy()))
```